# Remove hex values from data.table in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I have a large data table called Site (300,000 rows, 100 columns). Throughout the data table are hex values, for example: "\x96" or "\xc9." I want all of these values to be removed. They follow the format of "\x" followed by two characters (numbers or letters).

Here is the function that replaces values. I can do each individually as shown below, but I want a general command that will get rid of all hex values in the table.

```
Site<- as.data.table(apply(Site, 2, function(x) gsub("\x8e", "", x)))
```

I tried to use regular expression syntax, "\x..", but got this error:

```
Error: '\x' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\x"
```

How can I remove these hex values? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a reproducible example:

```
dt <- data.table(A = c("Th\xa1is","is","the","first\x12"), B = c("This","\x45is","the","second"))
```

I want "\xa1", "\x12", and "\x45" removed so the table looks like:

```
       A      B
1:  This   This
2:    is     is
3:   the    the
4: first second
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? `apply` is almost always a bad idea. The regex you describe would be `"\\x[a-ZA-Z0-9]{2}"`, I think.

Comment: @Frank `a-z` not `a-Z`. Probably just a typo though.

Comment: @ctwheels, you are right about the typo.

Comment: @Frank with the typo accounted for, the command does not remove the characters. I added an example also.

Comment: @Frank's [answer does work](https://regex101.com/r/LjnYLh/1) and you likely have something wrong with your code

Comment: @ctwheels Testing in R, I also see it failing, despite what that website says. I don't know enough to guess why, though.

Comment: @ctwheels here is the line I used with the example: `t <- as.data.table(apply(dt, 2, function(x) gsub("\\x[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}", "", x)))` The dt is does not change. However, I see that @Frank has the right regular expression.

Comment: @Frank is there a better way to do this without using apply?

Comment: @MichaelBerk Yeah. In this case, I think the idiom would be `dt[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "\\x[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}", replacement = "")]`. This use of `lapply` is pretty common in data.table and will show up if you look at the vignettes or other resources that are printed to console when you load data.table.

Comment: @Frank I ran it and it did not change the dt. I tried using lapply: `dt<- as.data.table(lapply(dt, function(x) gsub("\x\.\.", "", x)))` and got the error from the original post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mac, using RStudio.

Comment: Your requirement is quite incomprehensible to me. Why would you want to remove `"\x45"` which is the letter `"E"`? I'll guess you want to remove whatever is not between `"\x20"` and `"\x7e"`, that is the latin alphabet and a few other special characters. That'd give `dt[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "[^\x20-\x7e]", replacement = "")]`

Comment: If you remove all hex values, there's... nothing left.

Comment: except characters outside of a restricted ACSII alphabet... indeed you'd keep characters like that: `gsub("[\x01-\xff]", "", "日本語βa")` would give `"日本語"`, but I doubt that's what you want

Comment: @Aurèle that worked. Thank you so much. For the character columns with these hex values, the hex values show up within the text in "\xa1" format instead of a character. I think it was a problem with the encoding as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aurèle Looks answer-worthy, or maybe Michael could post it if you don't want to.

Comment: @Frank Sure. Though I'm not completely clear on the subject myself.

Answer (score 5):

You are confused. And so am I. And so are most of us. With characters, their encoding and their display.

The relevant sections of the help are hard to locate. `?Quotes` gives us a piece of the puzzle. `"\x"` or `"\x"` followed by anything but 1 or 2 digits (or letters between a and f) don't even make sense to the R parser.

Between `"\x01"` and `"\x7f"` you'll find the "traditional" ASCII table. `identical("\x30", "0")`, `identical("\x39", "9")`, `identical("\x41", "A")`, `identical("\x5A", "Z")`, for instance, are all `TRUE`.

Then in the 128 other values allowed by this notation, between `"\x80"` and `"\xff"`, you'll find the rest of the so-called "Latin 1" table.

Then there is Unicode for all other characters, and the ubiquitous UTF-8 encoding.

So when you say "remove all hex values", one can only assume those between `"\x80"` and `"\xff"` are the characters that trouble you. Maybe there's a problem with the way those characters are displayed. Or an encoding problem. Or some of them are just control characters. But let's just remove them all as you asked:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "[\x80-\xff]", replacement = "")]
```

should do. Or if you want to be even more radical, and remove everything that is not ASCII: `dt[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "[^\x01-\x7f]", replacement = "")]`.

Also noteworthy: R (unlike Python) doesn't have raw strings, and I suspect that's where the intial confusion in the comments stems from. Where in Python you can either do `"\\"` or `r"\"` to have an actual backslash in a string, in R, you can't. You only have the option to escape it: `"\\"`. In the regex101 example given, there is `Th\xa1is` in the test string. But this is different from what you have in R when you do `"Th\xa1is"`.
(*Edit:* Since R version 4.0, we now have raw strings: `r"(Th\xa1is)"` gives `[1] "Th\\xa1is"`)